# Insert data in database

Tags: vb.net

I have this code but when i try to execute it i always get a message box that says `Syntax error in INSERT statement` I dont know whats wrong. Can someone help me? I'm a newbie

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, 
            ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        If TextBox1.Text = "" Or TextBox2.Text = "" Or TextBox3.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("some fields are empty ")
            Exit Sub
        ElseIf TextBox2.Text <> TextBox3.Text Then
            MsgBox("password do not match ")
            Exit Sub
        Else
            ans = MsgBox(" are you want to ADD this user? ", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo,
                   "confirm ")
            If ans = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
                Try
                    Dim SqlQuery = "INSERT INTO login (user,pass) VALUES _ 
                      ('" & TextBox1.Text & "','" & TextBox2.Text & "')"
                    Dim sqlcommand As New OleDbCommand
                    With sqlcommand
                        .CommandText = SqlQuery
                        .Connection = conn
                        .ExecuteNonQuery()
                    End With
                    MsgBox("User Succesfully added", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
                    TextBox1.Text = ""
                    TextBox2.Text = ""
                    TextBox3.Text = ""

                Catch ex As Exception
                    MsgBox(ex.Message)
                End Try
            Else
                Exit Sub
            End If

        End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: where is connection object defined ?

Comment: what do you mean? im realy a newbee..

Comment: Where are you connection object is defined and is it connection is open ?

Comment: What's the content of TextBox1 and TextBox2? BTW: as soon as your query works, change it to use parameters instead of using string concatenation in order to avoid SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: textbox1 is the username for column user and textbox2 is password for column pass.. sir im definitely sure that my connection is open... sir i dont know how to parametarized it.. can you help me with it?please si

Answer (score 5):

Supposing that you are using MS-Access, the the word USER is a reserved keyword, you need to encapsulate it in square brackets

But let's try to use a parameterized query to solve also the problem with sql injection and single quotes in the password or username

```
Dim SqlQuery = "INSERT INTO login ([user],pass) VALUES (?,?)"
Dim sqlcommand As New OleDbCommand
With sqlcommand
    .CommandText = SqlQuery
    .Connection = conn
    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1",TextBox1.Text)
    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2",TextBox2.Text)
    .ExecuteNonQuery()
End With
```

The ? placeholders will be replaced by the actual value of the parameters defined in the Parameters collection of your command. When using OleDb the parameters are not recognized by their name (hence the anonymous placeholder) but, by their position. That means the first parameter in the collection replaces the first placeholder and so on.... By the way, the framework knows how to prepare propertly the value of string parameter (or date or decimal) putting the appropriate quote or decimal separator around the value

Comment: Still Syntax Error? This is weird.  Are you sure about the column names and table name?

Comment: im definitely sure sir

Comment: Can't imagine why you still get a syntax error, should be something different because that query should work. As a last idea, try to put the square brackets around [login] and [pass] ie `INSERT INTO [login] ([user],[pass]) VALUES (?,?)`

Comment: I can't help you without a sample copy of your database. If you wish you could post it on a shared file server (gdrive, skydrive, dropbox etc...) and share the link here (empty database of course)

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the other problems you're due to face (look up parameterised queries), you've concatenated your string incorrectly.

Change

```
Dim SqlQuery = "INSERT INTO login (user,pass) VALUES _ 
                  ('" & TextBox1.Text & "','" & TextBox2.Text & "')"
```

To:

```
Dim SqlQuery = "INSERT INTO login (user,pass) VALUES " & _ 
                  "('" & TextBox1.Text & "','" & TextBox2.Text & "')"
```